# Java: How to check with a scanner to see if a file contains integers or words?

Tags: java

I need to store a text file into a linked list. I am given a text file like:
1
2
3
4
5
When I try to say scanner.next it says there is a no element exception.
But I also need to account for a file like this:
Michael 
Hannah
Josephus
Ruth 
Matthew
So I can't just say nextInt because it could be a string.
How can I check if its integers or strings?
Thanks!
My code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
int k = 1;
String line = new String(sc.next());
ListNode nodes = new ListNode(n, null);
while(k < n - 1)
{
   line = sc.nextLine();
   nodes.setNext(new ListNode(n, null));
}
line = sc.nextLine();
ListNode last = new ListNode(n, null);
nodes.setNext(last);
return nodes;
```

Comment: I am not sure how to do it on the question page, but the file is all on different lines. For example, it goes 1 (enter) 2 (enter) etc.

Comment: Read the javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--

Comment: Andrew, please post your code and example files.

Comment: Oh! So I can just say hasNext or hasNextInt! I see, thank you so much!

Comment: @Andrew yes. You could also read everything in w/ next, keeping track of where the integers are. Then do Integer.parseInt() from each token with an int.

Comment: Just curious, could files contain mixed cases like `Michael 3 Hannah 4 2 6`? Or will they always be either all ints or all strings?

Comment: Always all strings or all ints

Comment: @AshwinGupta how would I build a circular linked list for the integers? A while-loop seems right but since I have to move the pointer how do I get the last one to point back front?

Comment: @Andrew honestly, I've never used a linked list before. I'll read the docs and test then get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for everything Ashwin. I checked it; just trying to print it out now.

Comment: @Andrew ok I think I get linked lists now. Be specific on circular, what do you mean by that? Are you talking about a double linked list where each node references the element behind and infront of it. Also, is there any reason you're implementing your own LinkedList? Java libs have a version of this already.

Comment: Just a (high) school class thing. Circular as in the last node points to the first node. Because of this, I cannot use a null check in my while loop to print.

Comment: @Andrew wait cant you just store the first node before you begin looping and then check on each iteration if you have the same hash code as the first node? Like `Node startNode = nodes.get(0);` `while() { //loop nodes, check if node's next reference is equal to start node using System.identity.HashCode()}` and in the while do `if(System.identityHashCode(nodes.get(n)) == System.identityHashCode(startNode)) break;`

Comment: @AshwinGupta yeah I did something similar to that.                                '     ListNode check = p;
      System.out.print(p.getValue() + " ");
      p = p.getNext();
      while(p.getValue() != check.getValue())
      {
         System.out.print(p.getValue() + " ");
         p = p.getNext();
      }'

Comment: @Andrew nice, glad you got it. The only issue with that is if your input file is like this: `1 2 3 1 4 5`

Comment: Right thats true. I think for my assignment it is ok to assume that each occurs only once. Btw, sorry I can't chat because I just got an SO so not enough reps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Scanner.next()` for all tokens, then simply do `Integer.parseInt()` for tokens with integers.

Here is an example:

```
File f = new File("myfile.txt");
Scanner scn = new Scanner(f);
String s = ""; 
while(scn.hasNext()) {
    s=scn.next();
    try {
       Integer.parseInt(s); 
       //if the code made it to this line, s is an int, handle at as such 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       //s is a string, handle it as such
    }
}
```

Just a word of advice, `hasNext()` will be true even if the next token is an integer. As such, you can't use `hasNext()` to determine if the file is composed of Ints or Strings. However, if you know in advanced that the file is of one type (no mixed cases), the following would also work:

```
if(scn.hasNextInt()) { //if true, you know that this file is ints
       while(scn.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = scn.nextInt(); //handle all as ints
       }
} else { //otherwise the file is strings
       while(scn.hasNext()) {
             String s = scn.next();
            //handle all as strings 
       }
}
```

Comment: But, since the file in my case will be either a strings or integers I can just use hasNextInt right?

Comment: @Andrew if you know there are no mixed cases, then yes. I hope that helps.